# How to integrate an external SDK on Android Studio?

Tags: android, audio, sdk, project

So I have made a project using standard Android Studios's sdks and recently found there was this  [Superpowered SDK](http://superpowered.com/music-analysis-bpm-key-detection-waveform#waveform) so can I use this  in my current project,if so, how can I?

Comment: Presumably, they have some documentation, and perhaps they have support channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their Github page [here](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine):

**How to create a Superpowered project with Android Studio**

[ Prerequisites: *latest Android SDK, Android NDK, Android Studio installed*. ]

Steps:

1. Create a new project in Android Studio.
2. Create the jni folder inside the project's folder: *app/src/main/jni*
3. Copy the contents of the following files from one of the example
   projects: *gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*,
   *local.properties, build.gradle, app/build.gradle*
4. Open *build.gradle* (Module: app), and change the applicationId (and
   moduleName if you like).